# append().ready() causing multiple code events | jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I'm having an issue with my code generation from an XHR request. The old javascript doesn't work on newly generated elements, therefore I must repeat code. I tried to handle this using the $(this) element, but old elements seem to be having multiple code events based on how many generations have occurred (code is being repeated).

I have gotten it to work using a dynamically changing class (.load_1, .load_2, .load3, etc...) that I assign to all new elements then pass as the $this, however this requires a lot of needless code.

Is there a simpler way of repeating js code to allow newly generated elements to function and maintaining the code from old elements that already exists (without code being repeated, i.e. first elm: two button presses after first generation, three button presses after second generation).

Calling threebar function after XHR request:

- $_rtn is from the server, giving the dom the num of items returned and the HTML generated by the database.
- $_rtn = [$num.'HTML']

```
                if ($status == 200) {
                  $_rtn = $_rtn.split('|,')
                  if (parseInt($_rtn[0]) > 0) {
                    posts.append($_rtn[1]).ready(function() {
                      load_threebar($(this))
                      post_media_click($(this))
                    })
                  }
                }
```

Threebar Function:

- This allows a button to be clicked and for built-in HTML to be generated that asks the user for an input.
- Every time a .threebar is clicked; I want all other .threebars that are open, to be closed.
- Currently, if a generated elem has an even number of click events, it closes immediately after opening. If it has an odd, it functions as it should.

```
function load_threebar($loadElem) {
  $loadElem.find(' .btn-threebar .threebar').click(function() {
    console.log('test')
    $this = $(this).parent()
    $('.threebar-list').fadeOut(150, function() {$(this).parent().removeClass('threebar-open'); $(this).remove();})
    if ($this.hasClass('threebar-open')) {
      $this.removeClass('threebar-open').find('.threebar-list').fadeOut(150, function(){$(this).remove()})
    } else {
      $this.addClass('threebar-open')
      gen_threebar($this)
    }
  })
}
```

Thank you for any help you can give!

Comment: The old events don't work on the new elements created via AJAX because they didn't exist when the events were bound when the DOM loaded. To fix this simply use delegated event handlers. See the duplicate for more information.

Comment: I added $(document).on('click', '.btn-threebar .threebar', function() {//code} and it works perfectly. Thank god I don't have to code it dynamic classes!